# Is there an equivalent widget in flutter to the "select multiple" element in HTML

Tags: select, button, widget, flutter, dropdown

I am searching for a widget in flutter that is equal to

```
<select multiple=""></select>
```

in flutter.

An example implementation (for the web) is [MaterializeCSS Select Multiple](https://materializecss.com/select.html)

As seen above I should be able to provide a list of items (with some of them preselected) and at the end retrieve a list of selected items or a map or something else.

An example implementation or a link to a documentation is very appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think that a widget like that currently exists in Flutter, but you can build one yourself.

On mobile phones with limited screen space it would probably make sense to display a dialog with a submit button, like [this native Android dialog](http://i2.wp.com/www.androidtutorialpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/list.png).

Here is a rough sketch how to implement such a dialog in less than 100 lines of code:

```
class MultiSelectDialogItem<V> {
  const MultiSelectDialogItem(this.value, this.label);

  final V value;
  final String label;
}

class MultiSelectDialog<V> extends StatefulWidget {
  MultiSelectDialog({Key key, this.items, this.initialSelectedValues}) : super(key: key);

  final List<MultiSelectDialogItem<V>> items;
  final Set<V> initialSelectedValues;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MultiSelectDialogState<V>();
}

class _MultiSelectDialogState<V> extends State<MultiSelectDialog<V>> {
  final _selectedValues = Set<V>();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.initialSelectedValues != null) {
      _selectedValues.addAll(widget.initialSelectedValues);
    }
  }

  void _onItemCheckedChange(V itemValue, bool checked) {
    setState(() {
      if (checked) {
        _selectedValues.add(itemValue);
      } else {
        _selectedValues.remove(itemValue);
      }
    });
  }

  void _onCancelTap() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _onSubmitTap() {
    Navigator.pop(context, _selectedValues);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Select animals'),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListTileTheme(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0),
          child: ListBody(
            children: widget.items.map(_buildItem).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('CANCEL'),
          onPressed: _onCancelTap,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: _onSubmitTap,
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(MultiSelectDialogItem<V> item) {
    final checked = _selectedValues.contains(item.value);
    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: checked,
      title: Text(item.label),
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      onChanged: (checked) => _onItemCheckedChange(item.value, checked),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
void _showMultiSelect(BuildContext context) async {
  final items = <MultiSelectDialogItem<int>>[
    MultiSelectDialogItem(1, 'Dog'),
    MultiSelectDialogItem(2, 'Cat'),
    MultiSelectDialogItem(3, 'Mouse'),
  ];

  final selectedValues = await showDialog<Set<int>>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return MultiSelectDialog(
        items: items,
        initialSelectedValues: [1, 3].toSet(),
      );
    },
  );

  print(selectedValues);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Love this. What if your list of values was dynamic?

Comment: How can i get text value in selected value?? @boformer

Comment: @urvashi you can use index 'selectedValues' in your list.

Comment: This almost solves a problem that I have, but is there a way to create a list of MultiSelectionDialogItem by passing in the number of items to be created along with the item id and item name and then print the selected values with a separation of some sort, like a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image: Multiple Selection Dialog]

In case you need a short and ready to use code, follow [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/multi-select-dialogue-in-flutter-a-versatile-approach-69ea0a598bac) article

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multiple_selection_dialogue_app/widgets/multi_select_dialog.dart';

/// A demo page that displays an [ElevatedButton]
class DemoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Stores the selected flavours
    List<String> flavours = [];

    return ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Flavours'),
        onPressed: () async {
          flavours = await showDialog<List<String>>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => MultiSelectDialog(
                          question: Text('Select Your Flavours'),
                          answers: [
                            'Chocolate',
                            'Caramel',
                            'Vanilla',
                            'Peanut Butter'
                          ])) ??
              [];
          print(flavours);
          // Logic to save selected flavours in the database
        });
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A Custom Dialog that displays a single question & list of answers.
class MultiSelectDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  /// List to display the answer.
  final List<String> answers;

  /// Widget to display the question.
  final Widget question;

  /// List to hold the selected answer
  /// i.e. ['a'] or ['a','b'] or ['a','b','c'] etc.
  final List<String> selectedItems = [];

  /// Map that holds selected option with a boolean value
  /// i.e. { 'a' : false}.
  static Map<String, bool> mappedItem;

  MultiSelectDialog({this.answers, this.question});

  /// Function that converts the list answer to a map.
  Map<String, bool> initMap() {
    return mappedItem = Map.fromIterable(answers,
        key: (k) => k.toString(),
        value: (v) {
          if (v != true && v != false)
            return false;
          else
            return v as bool;
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (mappedItem == null) {
      initMap();
    }
    return SimpleDialog(
      title: question,
      children: [
        ...mappedItem.keys.map((String key) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (_, StateSetter setState) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(key), // Displays the option
                value: mappedItem[key], // Displays checked or unchecked value
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.platform,
                onChanged: (value) => setState(() => mappedItem[key] = value)),
          );
        }).toList(),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(visualDensity: VisualDensity.comfortable),
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Clear the list
                  selectedItems.clear();

                  // Traverse each map entry
                  mappedItem.forEach((key, value) {
                    if (value == true) {
                      selectedItems.add(key);
                    }
                  });

                  // Close the Dialog & return selectedItems
                  Navigator.pop(context, selectedItems);
                }))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multiple_selection_dialogue_app/pages/demo_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: DemoPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```